# Story in which some people cause technological systems to fail

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for the name and author associated with a story that I read in a magazine (probably *Analog*) in the mid 1990s.

The primary conceit was that there exist certain people around whom machines, computers etc. simply fail more often then they do when these folks are not around. There is a log-scale for denoting how strong the effect is.

Other useful tidbits:

- It may have been one of a running time-line.
- It took place at a special facility on the moon---out of the way of others who might come to harm---with heavy redundancy of simple systems to provide atmospheric services, food, etc . and where these people have been (voluntarily, I believe) concentrated for research purposes.
- The narrator notes that everyone in this select group owns their own crowbar (using it to achieve egress from their own cubicle after a failure of the door...)
- It involved a nanotech spacesuit design.
- There is mention of a no-fly zone around the facility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was it [Down Under Crater Billy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43609) by Stephen L. Burns?

The nanotech spacesuit was essentially a sheet of nanobots over a passage, and simply walking through it put it on and activated it.  There was also an incident where

> an automated kitchen generated a thanksgiving dinner with far too much tryptophan and rendered a good number of the inhabitants unconscious.

Comment: That is the one. Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit in some description of this book? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here, since if the link dies, the answer is rendered almost useless.

Comment: Actually, looks like the link *has* died. Maybe you could find a brief description of the book from elsewhere?

Comment: I added a little more description from what I remember, but couldn't find a more useful link.  Changed that one to a bibliographic index.

Comment: Updated answer -- As the link illustrated, the interior illustration was by [William R. Warren, Jr](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?110799), and the story was *written* by [Stephen L. Burns](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43609).  (Thanks for the heads-up, @studog!  Nice catch.)