# I'm looking for a tale that features an outcast colony on the moon

Tags: story-identification, moon

The points I recall:

- colony on the moon
- populated by people that naturally just cause technological malfunction
- colony is self-sufficient: they charge earth-bound corps a testing fee on new tech
- one of the items under test is an airlock made up of a mesh of nanobots: you can just walk through and the nanobots seal around you

I read it once, enjoyed, want to reread and can't for the life of me google up the title or author.

Thanks in advance.

...Stu

Comment: So... "tale" - short story? Book? Poem? You said that you read it so I'm going to assume it wasn't a movie or TV show...

Comment: Outcast colony on the moon? [These guys](http://i.imgur.com/IEhvR00.jpg), perhaps?

Comment: Probably the same as my earlier question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23672/story-in-which-some-people-cause-technological-systems-to-fail

Comment: @dmckee: I believe my question is a duplicate of yours. Thanks!

Comment: @dmckee My question is a duplicate. I found a website that appears to have (poorly) OCRed the story, and it is the one I was looking for. If there's a way to close my question as duplicate, please do so. Or convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it.